# How to add and subtract input value with minimum and maximum attribute. Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a form where the user can add and subtract from the value of the input field in this case to display a number of children.

Naturally I can add and subtract from the number which displays on my screen, however the actual value stays the same at 0 when I check in console. It is important for me to be able to check this value so I can set a minimum and a maximum amount.

How do I make sure the value changes on click of my buttons?

JS:

```
childVal = $('#pageSearch-children').val();
minValueChild = $('#pageSearch-children').attr('min');
maxValueChild = $('#pageSearch-children').attr('max');

if (childVal < maxValueChild) {
    $('.add').click(function () {
        $('#pageSearch-children').val( function(i, oldval) {
            return ++oldval;
        });
        $('#pageSearch-children').val() + 1;
    });
}
if (childVal > minValueChild) {
    $('.sub').click(function () {
        $('#pageSearch-children').val( function(i, oldval) {
            return --oldval;
        });
        $('#pageSearch-children').val() - 1;
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
<h3 class="white black">
    <input class="backgroundNoneInput" type="number" value="0" id="pageSearch-children" name="children" min="0" max="{{ $property--property_sleeps or '99' }}"> 
</h3>
<button type="button" class="sub backgourndNoneButt">
    <span class="white fa fa-minus fa-2x faPlusMin" aria-hidden="true">                      
    </span>
</button>
<button type="button" class="add backgourndNoneButt">
    <span class="white fa fa-plus fa-2x faPlusMin" aria-hidden="true">                        
    </span>
</button>
```

Comment: Create a JsFiddle so we know what you're trying to do

Comment: @Grasper here we go, thanks dude! https://jsfiddle.net/89f30jov/1/

Comment: your if statements need to be inside your "click" functions, not the other way round. Right now it only ever evalutes those if statements once, when the page is first created. And consequently only ever at most 1 of your button click handlers will ever be added.

Answer (score 3):

I would surgest you change your code to the following in order to make it work better:

```
childVal = $('#pageSearch-children').val();
minValueChild = $('#pageSearch-children').attr('min');
maxValueChild = $('#pageSearch-children').attr('max');
$('.add').click(function() {
  if (childVal < maxValueChild) {
    $('#pageSearch-children').val(function(i, oldval) {
      return ++oldval;
    });
    childVal = $('#pageSearch-children').val();
  }
});
$('.sub').click(function() {
  if (childVal > minValueChild) {
    $('#pageSearch-children').val(function(i, oldval) {
      return --oldval;
    });
    childVal = $('#pageSearch-children').val();
  }
});
```

One of the problems is that your `$('.sub').click` would never run since it would never pass `if (childVal > minValueChild) {` in your originale code.

**demo**

```js
childVal = $('#pageSearch-children').val();
minValueChild = $('#pageSearch-children').attr('min');
maxValueChild = $('#pageSearch-children').attr('max');
$('.add').click(function() {
  if (childVal < maxValueChild) {
    $('#pageSearch-children').val(function(i, oldval) {
      return ++oldval;
    });
    childVal = $('#pageSearch-children').val();
  }
});
$('.sub').click(function() {
  if (childVal > minValueChild) {
    $('#pageSearch-children').val(function(i, oldval) {
      return --oldval;
    });
    childVal = $('#pageSearch-children').val();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 class="white black">
  <input class="backgroundNoneInput" type="number" value="0" id="pageSearch-children" name="children" min="0" max="99" readonly> Children
</h3>
<button type="button" class="sub backgourndNoneButt">
    <span class="white fa fa-minus fa-2x faPlusMin" aria-hidden="true">   sub                   
    </span>
</button>
<button type="button" class="add backgourndNoneButt">
    <span class="white fa fa-plus fa-2x faPlusMin" aria-hidden="true">      add                  
    </span>
</button>
```

Comment: @DicedMango No problem, happy to help

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing but adding two fields together and if the both exceed the maximum amount the buttons are disabled.. I have added to fiddlejs.. if you could help i would be very grateful: https://jsfiddle.net/dghLm6f7/1/